# JavaScript runtime error: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmpStartDate' is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have been trying to resolve this error for days and I have made no progress so decided to try here. I can appreciate this type of error can be difficult to both explain and respond to but I will try my best.

I have inherited an ASP.NET web application written in C# and uses a lot of JavaScript for validation etc. The application does work except for one particular area. Every image that represents a calendar, when clicked on, produces this error:

JavaScript runtime error: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_**name of text box'** is undefined

However, the textbox that is referenced is defined in every instance, e.g:

```
 <asp:TextBox id="txtEmpStartDate" runat="server" Width="165px" ReadOnly="false" CssClass="enable" TabIndex="2" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
        <a id="A1"  onclick="ShowCal(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmpStartDate,this,'Add,Edit')" style="cursor:pointer">
```

The ShowCal Java function is also present on the same page:

```
    //This function displays the calendar
function ShowCal(txtid,obj,mode)
{   
    displayCalendar(txtid,'dd/mm/yyyy',obj);
}
```

The displayCalendar function is present in a separate .js file.

Everything seems to be present and yet this error appears when clicking on and calendar image in the application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am running this in Visual Studio for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: Have you willing to set static ID using `ClientIDMode="Static"`? It's easier than dynamically generated ID since `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmpStartDate` may not be the control ID you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Also, I have seen this application working - the calendar appearing - on a different deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing controlId as ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmpStartDate, you can directly use this object in your javascript function.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtEmpStartDate" runat="server" Width="165px" ReadOnly="false" CssClass="enable" TabIndex="2" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox> 

<a id="A1"  onclick="ShowCal(<%=txtEmpStartDate.ClientID %>,obj,'Add,Edit')" style="cursor:pointer">test</a>


//This function displays the calendar
    function ShowCal(txtid,obj,mode)
    {   
        displayCalendar($(txtid).attr('id'),'dd/mm/yyyy',obj);
    }
```